# Custom Google Map Marker like in Trulia map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to make Google Map markers like the one used in Trulia map?

1. The markers have pointer in the bottom
2. <strike>The markers have price labels.</strike>
3. <strike>The markers seems to have variable length depend on the label inside them.</strike>
4. <strike>The markers can change color when it's being hovered (grey color) or it's already clicked (orange color) beside its normal color (green).</strike>

Is there a library for this?

Screenshot is below

[image]

**UPDATE**

So far I found a library [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) and I can reproduce the 2, 3, and 4 above. See below for the code.
But I can't seem to put a pointer in the bottom of the label.

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/p8YhU/

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: homeLatLng,
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "$425K",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    icon: {},
    isClicked: false
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.isClicked = true;
    marker.set('labelClass', 'labels active');
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    marker.set('labelClass', 'labels hover');
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    if (marker.isClicked){
        marker.set('labelClass', 'labels active');
    } else {
        marker.set('labelClass', 'labels');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Previous answer was

But there is another problem. It seems when you display the icon, the pointer of the label doesn't really point to the marker. see this http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/y3M4u/.

The MarkerWithLabel does give `labelAnchor` property to set (see [this](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0.1/docs/reference.html)). But when the label is too long, the anchor positioning will be broken too.

Comment: maybe this can help you http://jsfiddle.net/2a9aj/

Comment: awesome, why I didn't think of that. thanks! here's my updated one. http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/N7gsd/

Comment: `MarkwithLable` is unavailable right now. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help you [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2a9aj)

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: homeLatLng,
    draggable: true,
    raiseOnDrag: true,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "<div class='arrow'></div><div class='inner'>$425K</div>",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    icon: {},
    isClicked: false
});
```

and css

```
.labels {
    margin-top:-3px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1030;
}
.labels .arrow{
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-right-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-width: 5px 5px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-style: solid;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.labels .inner{
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Comment: it's a small detail but make me curious. can you give a border for the arrow?

Comment: no I think, arrow is border (http://screencast.com/t/7tVoFfYWO), if need boarder on inner and arrow maybe need use background image with arrow

Comment: exactly, i thought so. just a minor detail, not very important. thanks a lot!

Comment: please add the code changes that solved the issue to the body of your answer

Comment: met another problem, it seems when you display the icon, the pointer of the label doesn't really point to the marker. see this http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/y3M4u/. updated the question. this is quite a big deal, i think.

Comment: for this try play with 'labelAnchor' property, example http://jsfiddle.net/8jQpJ/