# Google Maps: How to make custom markes like Airbnb?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a map with custom markers like Airbnb:

[image]

That is, the marker with price number and square look. The code is like this:

```
<div class="map-marker" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0.01; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 267px; top: 237px; z-index: 238; display: block; cursor: pointer;" onselectstart="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" title="">
  <div class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-middle tooltip-layout tooltip-primary">
    <div class="price-marker__label">
      <div class="price-label">
        <sup class="currency-prefix">$</sup>
        <span class="price-amount">108</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought it would be very easy. Define a custom html marker component, pass it to the google maps with its coordinates, and it will be there.

But it seems more complex than that.

I find [Custom Google Map Marker like in Trulia map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051244/custom-google-map-marker-like-in-trulia-map). it is very similar to my question. However the `MarkwithLable` is unavailable now.

What I can find in Google API document is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels . This is only a simple marker with a lable. And I don't see any custom HTML compoment pass in.

---

UPDATE:

I think RichMarker(https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker), maybe what I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing but this Rich Marker library isn't supported anymore. Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your custom marker types, and then assign them as you wish....

Have you worked through /this/?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers

Comment: Completely missed this tutorial, this is extremely helpful.

Comment: Indeed, it should give you exactly what you need.